# Vue dynamically load elements upon selection of the drop-down

Tags: vue.js

I need a single drop-down field on initial page load: 
[image]

When the item from this drop-down is selected I need to load yet another drop-down with the same items:

[image]

After that same procedure:

[image]

I am able to hard-code it, but obviously it is not a good practice, since my repetition is limited by how many elements I put, besides reading the values becomes a problem because I have different v-model names for each input:

```
<div>
    <label class='labelForm'>ORGANIZATION TO BE NOTIFIED:</label><br>
    <select :class="{defaultSelect : newAlert.productFamily === ''}" class='dropdownForm serviceForm' v-model='newAlert.productFamily'>
        <option selected disabled value=''>Select</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
     </select>

     <select v-if="newAlert.productFamily != ''" :class="{defaultSelect : newAlert.productFamily2 === ''}" class='dropdownForm serviceForm' v-model='newAlert.productFamily2'>
        <option selected disabled value=''>Select</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
     </select>

     <select v-if="newAlert.productFamily2 != ''" :class="{defaultSelect : newAlert.productFamily3 === ''}" class='dropdownForm serviceForm' v-model='newAlert.productFamily3'>
        <option selected disabled value=''>Select</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to load dynamically those drop-downs and read the values alltogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
<select
    v-for="(dropdown, index) in dropdowns"
    :key="index"
    v-if="index === 0 || dropdowns[index - 1].selected !== null"
    v-model="dropdown.selected"
>
    <option :value="null" selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option
        v-for="option in dropdown.options"
        :key="option"
        :value="option"
        v-text="option"
    ></option>
</select>
```

--

```
data() {
    return {
        dropdowns: [
            {
                selected: null,
                options: [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                    'Option 3'
                ]
            },
            {
                selected: null,
                options: [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                    'Option 3'
                ]
            },
            {
                selected: null,
                options: [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                    'Option 3'
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

If the options are always the same:

```
<select
    v-for="(dropdown, index) in dropdowns"
    :key="index"
    v-if="index === 0 || dropdowns[index - 1].value !== null"
    v-model="dropdown.value"
>
    <option :value="null" selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option
        v-for="option in options"
        :key="option"
        :value="option"
        v-text="option"
    ></option>
</select>
```

...

```
data() {
    return {
        options: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
        dropdowns: [{ value: null }, { value: null }, { value: null }]
    }
}
```

If you want all the values together you could create a computed property:

```
computed: {
    dropdownValues() {
        return this.dropdowns.map(d => d.selected)
    }
}
```

Comment: it kind of works, but the idea was to get the options also dynamically, and also the options list will be always the same. Would it be possible to point to it only once? Instead of writing it in the data() { return ... ?

Comment: <option v-for='option in options'>{{ option }}</option>

Comment: I've edited my answer with the case where options are always the same.

Comment: - <select v-model="dropdown">: You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array becaus
e writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, I wrote that without testing. You can do `dropdowns: [{ value: null }, { value: null }, { value: null },]` in `data`, `dropdowns[index - 1].value !== null` in `v-if` and `dropdown.value` in `v-model`. Corrected in answer.